# what is the type of architecture of EfficientNetB2?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

As the architecture type of :

- VGG16 and VGG19 is linear
- ResNet-50 is Residual blocks
- InceptionV3 is Inception module

what is the type of architecture of EfficientNetB2 ?

Comment: i want to know the type of the architecture of EfficientNetB2, i gave an exemple of type of other architectures to make my question clearer.

Comment: the type of VGG19 architecture is linear but the type of architecture of ResNet 50 is Residual blocks .. so i want to know what's about EfficientNetB2??

Comment: that's the name of the architecture not the type

Comment: i'm doing a table of the charestirestic of the Cnn architectures : name, type of architecture , number of layers , input size and Parameters.

Comment: there are type of each architecture :VGG16 and VGG19 is linear
ResNet-50 is Residual blocks
InceptionV3 is Inception module

Comment: but i didn't know what's the type of EfficientNetB2??

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear definition of what does "neural network architecture" mean. People would often would use the term for the models described in the papers, so LeNet-5 became "LeNet-5 architecture", etc. But if you change something about the model, would it be a different architecture? If "architectures" can be confusing, grouping them into "types" is even harder. For example, if you add residual connections over LSTM layers, is this a new architecture? Is it of LSTM or "residual connections" type? Most of neural networks are glued together of many different building blocks, so the decision on what defines the type of the architecture would be rather arbitrary. To complicate this even more, there are known examples of deep learning results being hard to reproduce when changing some of the hyperparameters, using a different optimization algorithm, or even different implementation. What I'm trying to say is that there is no single or definite classification like that, nor it would make much sense, at least at this stage of our understanding of neural networks.